# How do I kill the Enderdragon?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been battling away at this thing for a while, I always end up dead. I'm assuming you need to use some kind of trick or tactic to beat it, any idea what I should be doing?

Comment: Protip: [To defeat the Enderdragon, shoot at it until it dies.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NZexy.jpg) From what I've read, the dragon is designed to simply be dumb hard: "[If I can beat it all all, it's too easy](http://twitter.com/#!/notch/status/123685334306390016)", said Notch.

Comment: @badp I have heard conflicting reports from people who got it to spawn in pre-5...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

OK, this seems to be the basics of the strategy required:

1. Destroy the Ender Crystals that are on top of the obsidian towers. Until this is done, the Ender Dragon will keep regenerating at an impossible rate.
2. Kill it by shooting at it until it dies.

   > [?????](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoMdJApZsgk&feature=player_detailpage#t=116s)
3. Credits

Comment: I've seen suggestions that you need to shoot its head, but I haven't confirmed this.

Comment: I moved a bunch of my cheapo swords, bows, and arrows from mob spawner xp grinders down near the portal and set up a bed.  I had a small supply of pumpkins and stacks of dirt, took a few trips but I got him using this strategy!  Then you can sit back and enjoy the meta transcendentalist credits

Comment: "I've tried killing the ender dragon the second time with my enchanting sword it worked." - "Make a diamond enchanted sword to kill tap with sword 10 times" ~ by anonymous

Answer (score 18):

I use the following strategy in survival mode:

1. **Avoid Enderman Attack:**
   Wear a pumpkin hat.
2. **Destroy the Crystals:**
   Shoot them with arrows.
3. **Dragon:**
   Stay in water (which also helps keep endermen away) and attack it with everything I've got!

Comment: Do Endermen stay away if you're wearing a pumpkin?

Comment: @fredley - wearing a pumpking means you never look at them and thus will never accidentally aggro them by mousing over them.

Comment: @RavenDreamer mad!

Answer (score 8):

1. Make a bed beside the end portal in the real world and sleep in it.
2. Destroy the crystals on the towers. (Watch out for Endermen!) You can destroy the crystals by mining them, attacking them, or shooting them with a bow and arrow. (TIP: The crystals will explode so it's recommended to destroy them with a bow and arrow or snowballs.)
3. Build your way up on to a tower with a common block like dirt.
4. Keep shooting at the dragon with a bow and arrow and when the dragon is close, swipe at it with a powerful sword like iron or diamond.

More tips:

1. After you beat the dragon a portal and egg will appear. The portal will give you an 8 minute long "script" giving you details about the game.
2. Press the Escape key (Esc) on your keyboard to skip the epic "script" and spawn back to your world.
3. Exiting the world or turning off your computer when viewing the "script", and then going back, the game will act as you never beaten the ender dragon.
4. Watch the "Script", it's epic!
5. When you enter The End, you get an achievement called "The End"?
6. Infinity is an enchantment for the bow where you can fire unlimited arrows as long as you have one arrow in your inventory, this is useful for fighting the Ender Dragon because you won't need to stack up on arrows.
7. The Ender Dragon will drop 20000 xp.
8. The best way to get the dragon egg is with a piston.
9. Once you "beat the game", you can continue playing your world.
10. When you enter the portal to go back to over world, you get the achievement "The End" .
11. You can't exit The End unless you beat the dragon.

Answer (score 5):

It will deflect any arrows that don't hit its head or soft underbelly. So yeaah, weakspots.
Link to Minecraft Wiki entry, it's in paragraph 3: [EnderDragon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enderdragon)

Answer (score 1):

This was in creative mode. All I did was destroy the Energy Crystals and fly around following it shooting snowballs at it until it died.

Comment: How do you fly around?

Comment: He was in creative mode

Answer (score 0):

I would destroy the obsidian towers, then kill it with a enchanted bow (flame, power, ect).

Comment: This doesn't really add any value to answers already provided.